# How to find basis for subspace of $P_n(R)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm working on an exercise in Friedberg's *Linear Algebra*. The exercise is as follows

For a fixed $a \in R$, determine the dimension of the subspace of $P_n(R)$ defined by $S = \{f \in P_n(R) \ |\ f(a) = 0 \} $.

(The answer in the book is $n-1$)

This is my work so far:

---

We begin by considering an arbitrary element $f \in S$. We express $f$ as 
\begin{align}
f(x) = b_0 + b_1x + b_2x^2 + \cdots + b_nx^n.
\end{align}
  Since $f(a) = 0$, it follows that 
\begin{align*}
  f(a) &= b_0 + b_1a + b_2a^2 + \cdots + b_na^n \\
  0    &= b_0 +  \sum_{k=1}^n b_ka^k\\
  b_0  &= -(\sum_{k=1}^n b_ka^k) \\
  b_0  &= -b_1a - b_2a^2 - \cdots - b_na^n
\end{align*}
Reinserting this expression into our expression for $f(x)$, we have

\begin{align*}
  f(x) &= b_0 + b_1x + b_2x^2 + \cdots + b_nx^n \\
       &= (-b_1a - b_2a^2 - \cdots - b_na^n) + b_1x + b_2x^2 + \cdots + b_nx^n \\
       &= b_1(x-a) + b_2(x^2 - a^2) + b_3(x^3 - a^3) + \cdots + b_n(x^n - a^n)\\
\end{align*}

---

I'm terribly confused for the following reasons:

1. If we let $b_1 = -(x+a)$ , $b_2 = 1$, and $b_3, \cdots , b_n = 0$, then we have a nontrivial solution to the homogeneous equation.
2. I'm having difficulty understanding how the value of $x$ affects answers to the homogeneous equation. For instance, if we let $x = a$ in this equation, then clearly the equation equals $0$ (by hypothesis).
3. It seems to me that we could do the same thing as in (1.) for $x^2 - a^2$ and $x^4 - a^4$. That is, let $b_2 = -(x^2+a^2)$, let $b_4 = 1$, and the remaining coefficients equal $0$. Could we not do this for many of the terms of the form $b_{2k}(x^{2k} - a^{2k})$, producing many nontrivial solutions to the equation?

I feel as though I'm misunderstanding something fundamental about working with polynomial spaces. How do I determine the dimension of this subspace, and what role does the value of $x$ have to do with respect to the dimension of the subspace?

Comment: Since $\dim S=n$, not $n-1$, there is something wrong here. Are you sure that your definition of $P_n(\mathbb R)$ is the correct one?

Comment: Perhaps there is a typo in the textbook. The answer in the back of the book states $n-1$. My definition of $P_n(R)$ is "The vector space of polynomials of degree less than or equal to $n$."

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following linear map $\phi$ from $P_n(x)$ to $R$:
\begin{equation}
\phi(f)=f(a). 
\end{equation}

Then $\text{ker}(\phi)=S$ and $\dim(\text{im}(\phi))=1$. By Rank-Nullity Theorem,
\begin{equation}
\dim(\text{ker}(\phi))=\dim(P_n(x))-\dim(\text{im}(\phi))=n+1-1=n.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$S$ is the subspace of polynomials $f \in P_n(\mathbb R)$ such that $x-a$ divides $f$. To obtain this result consider the Euclidean division of $f$ by $x-a$.

Therefore $\dim S= n$. And a basis of $P_n(\mathbb R)$ is $x-a, (x-a)x, \dots, (x-a)x^{n-1}$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not understanding how one goes from $b_1(x-a) + b_2(x^2 - a^2) + b_3(x^3 - a^3) + \cdots + b_n(x^n - a^n)$ to the statement that "$S$ is the subspace of polynomials $f \in P_n(R)$ such that $x-a$ divides $f$. Or is my work incorrect/unnecessary in coming to that conclusion?

Comment: You can prove that $x^k-x^k$ can be divided by $x-a$ for all $p$. But an easier way is to consider the Euclidean division of $f$ by $x-a$.